# Please remove the hyperlink in the sentence "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Tags: discussion, chat, culture

Under certain conditions, the following message appears:

> "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. **Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?**"

except with a hyperlink on the bold text, and clicking the hyperlink (whether intentionally or by accident) creates a new chat room. This leads to some sites having **trillions** of chat rooms, which is something that we absolutely do not want.

I submitted a feature request on Meta SE to help us "avoid" making trillions of chat rooms: [Avoiding making so many new chatrooms called "Discussion between user[A] and user [B]" which later become frozen or not very useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353643/391772). It was well-received by Shog9 but no current SE employees seem to have interacted with it.

I suspect that it's not likely that code development is going to happen any time soon for SE Chat. If that's true, ***Then please just remove the hyperlink.*** That's all we ask. We don't want new rooms created. [We have our own system](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/268/5) for moving conversations to Chat. We have a small and maintainable number of rooms, and a very, very small number of deleted rooms (these were due to people "accidentally" or "spuriously" clicking the link that we are asking you to remove).